# zf.bat not responding, no error msg no confirmation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have downloaded the full version of Zend Framework.

I have unzipped the package, included the necessary library and bin paths, in php.ini as well as windows variables / path.

When I am in command line, and try to create a project nothing happens.

No error msg, no project creation, no nothing.

Any suggestions?

I am new to PHP, and am using XAMPP, I have also included the library zend folder in xampp\php folder, as this erases the need of editing php.ini file ( I have done it anyways)

I believ I have done everything right, but nothing happens and am a little under time pressure. I hope someone can help.

---

### EDIT

in CMD I type:
*zf.bat create project %project\Path%*

It just creates a new line. And in the PHP.ini file I have the line
*include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\php\zend\library"*

I am running it as admin, I have also created tutorial standard test PHP scripts and run the server successfuly. Just unable to use zend. CMD does not complain about the command, which leaves me to believe i set at least the variables right and its reckognised as an command.The issue seems to lie within Zend !?

Comment: are yu running the command prompt in admin mode?

Comment: What exactly are you typing into the command line and what happens in response? *Something* is bound to happen, isn't it?

Comment: zf.bat create project C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject

Comment: and it just starts a new line. And yes I am the administrator

Comment: @Pekka ^ ; it seems to recognise it as an command as it doesnt complain, but nothing happens ! -

Comment: `php.exe` needs to be in your environment `PATH` for this to work as well.  If you open a command prompt and type `php.exe -v` do you get valid output or does it say `php is not recognized as an internal or external command...`?

Comment: no, it returns php info ! and mentions zend tecjnology !!

Comment: in cmd go to the folder where zf.bat is placed, type `zf.bat create project C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject`, wait for 1-2 mins and then share with us the response